# How are macros finally determined in configure?

Tags: c, configure

```
#if (NGX_SOLARIS)

    ngx_int_t   i;
    size_t      size;

#endif
```

I know that `NGX_SOLARIS` is finally determined when we run `./configure`,but how are these macros actually defined,can you provide a detailed example that demonstrates how most `./configure` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./configure` runs through all the checks for what your system's platform is, what capabilities your compiler has, etc. and then it uses `automake` to generate Makefiles with stuff like `CPPFLAGS` which define the macros it needs to pass to the preprocessor during compilation.

This is all part of the GNU build system: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/gnu.html

Comment: can you provide a hello world example to use the build sys?